# Group-Object by arrays within a hashtable - behavior changed with v5

Tags: powershell, .net-framework-version, powershell-5.0

The behavior of `Group-Object` seems to have changed between PS v4 and v5 when grouping by array values in a hashtable. The rationale for using `GetEnumerator()` is beyond the scope of this example, which I've tried to keep simple.

```
$ht = @{}
$orchard1 = "orange","lemon","lime"
$orchard2 = "apple","pear"
$orchard3 = "apple","pear"
$orchard4 = "orange","lemon","lime"
$ht.Add("o1",$orchard1)
$ht.Add("o2",$orchard2)
$ht.Add("o3",$orchard3)
$ht.Add("o4",$orchard4)
$htEn = $ht.GetEnumerator() | select Name, Value
$htEn | Group-Object -Property Value
```

On PS versions 2-4, the output is

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 {apple, pear}             {@{Name=o3; Value=System.Object[]}, @{Name=o2; Value=System.Object[]}}
    2 {orange, lemon, lime}     {@{Name=o1; Value=System.Object[]}, @{Name=o4; Value=System.Object[]}}
```

which is very handy. On PS versions 5.0 and 5.1, the output is

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    4 {orange, lemon, lime}     {@{Name=o4; Value=System.Object[]}, @{Name=o2; Value=System.Object[]}, @{Name=o1; Va...
```

which is less helpful, because the mis-matching pairs of arrays are all grouped together.

What changed? Is there a simple way to get v5+ to handle this situation like the previous versions?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600414/what-change-in-powershell-5-changes-meaning-of-block-curly-brackets

Comment: Thanks, `-Property {$_.Value -Join "|"}` gets the behavior I want in v5. Feel free to post an answer. [Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/04/19/use-a-script-block-to-create-custom-groupings-in-powershell/)'s more on the semi-documentedness of passing a scriptblock to the Property argument. The bug-or-feature aspects are mostly academic, I guess.